# Try/Catch not catching exception in VS 2010

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, try-catch

I'm having a very strange occurrence in VS2010 C#.  I'm using a WCF PubSub framework with callbacks over netTcpBinding.  Strangely in one code block within my large solution an exception is being thrown (which I totally expect and am coding towards) but the debugger is stopping showing the exception being thrown as if there is no try or catch.  Now when I run the application outside VS as just the .exe the program does not crash and the exceptions are being handled accordingly.  What's even stranger is when I created a lightweight version of this app inside a new blank solution, the exceptions are being caught in VS during debug mode, but when I added this same lightweight project to the original large project again the exceptions are not being caught.  Here's the block of code, although I think the issue is something to do with the settings in VS for this solution, that's my only guess.

Basically, when a client closes unexpectedly and the service tries to send to a faulted client/subscriber the catch will handle this and just remove the subscriber from the list.  The List of _subscribers is static readonly list.  I've tried making the service singleton and not using a static keyword on the list, but it seems to make no difference.  I can't zip and post the entire solution which this resides in for obvious reasons.

```
public void UpdateData(Action<T> action)
{
 _subscribers.ForEach(subscriber =>
           {
               var client = subscriber as ICommunicationObject;
               try
               {
                 if (client != null && client.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                     action(subscriber);
                 else
                     Unsubscribe(subscriber);
               }
               catch
               {
                 Unsubscribe(subscriber);
               }
            }
 );
}
```

Comment: Maybe you accidentally activated this setting? http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/visual-studio-break-when-exception-thrown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heinzi's answer above fixed the issue, it can be resolved here:

http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/visual-studio-break-when-exception-thrown/

Comment: Dead link. It's usually bad practice to just link to outside sources like this in case they go down. Too bad :/

Answer (score 2):

I'd look into your `Exceptions` settings. I would consider replacing with the following cleaner logic:

```
           try
           {
             if (client != null && client.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                 action(subscriber);

           }
           finally
           {
             Unsubscribe(subscriber);
           }
```

Comment: Thank you, I should probably be using a finally instead of an empty catch statement.  Heinzi's link fixed the issue, have no idea how or when I set that option but that was what the issue was.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The link of the Heinzi's answer is dead but has been archived here :

https://web.archive.org/web/20120126024551/http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/visual-studio-break-when-exception-thrown/

Here is a copy of the text.
Btw, it didn't help in my case ...

---

Visual Studio Break When Exception Thrown

By default, Visual Studio will only break when an exception is unhandled in user code.  This is often some distance from where the actual exception took place, as several try...catch blocks might have been involved in the meantime before the exception goes unhandled.  A recent thread on the ALT.NET mailing list discussed some techniques for getting round this issue if you the developer would really like to see exactly the line of code that is failing.  One such technique (Jon Davis) used precompilation directives to conditionally add the try-catch statements, like so:

```
void MyMethod()

    {
    #if !DEBUG
                    try 
                    {
    #endif
     
                                    // the logic that might throw
                                    DoSomething();
     
    #if !DEBUG
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                                    LogError(e);
                                    // etc…
                    }
    #endif
    }
```

This gets pretty ugly fast, but it gets the job done.  However, another list member (Nick Blumhardt) wrote in and pointed out a feature of Visual Studio that effectively does this for you if it's the desired behavior.  From the Debug menu, choose Exceptions (or use Ctrl-Alt-E) which brings up this dialog:

image

If you check the box under Thrown for Common Language Runtime Exceptions, the debugger will break on the line where it occurs rather than when it goes unhandled in some catch block.  The downside to using this option is that it applies to all code, not just a particular method.  You can mix and match the two techniques if you only want certain code blocks to break when the exception is thrown, but personally I would avoid the former technique as I think it results in uglier code that is less clear, and doesn't behave the same under development as in production.

It's also worth pointing out that Visual Basic can use Catch Exception When {expression} to achieve this quite easily.  For instance, a DEBUG flag could be used for the When condition.  This would still result in code that differs in behavior between DEBUG and production, but at least it's far more elegant and easier to read and maintain.  C#, unfortunately, lacks such a feature.